# SPeL convert String to Integer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

I have a property for example in application.yml for Spring boot.

```
some:
  strNumber: "5"
```

I want to base-off some other property's value of this property. For example

```
some-other:
    intNumber: ${some.strNumber * 50}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I am totally no sure but can you try 
some-other:
    intNumber: ${some.strNumber} * 50

Comment: That evaluates to a String `"4 * 50"`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that $ is used to read property not to evaluate spring expression. https://www.dev2qa.com/spring-expression-language-example-vs/

Comment: So how can I do it with `#{}`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add two different property

```
some:
  strNumber: 5

some-other:
threadHold: 50
```

In code on property you use spring el expression:

```
@Value("#{some.strNumber} * {some-other.threadHold}}")
private Long add;// answer will be 250
```